# how to record video in one device at that same time play that video live in another device

Tags: android, record, video-capture, video-recording

I have to record video by using camera in one android device,at that same time i have to play that recording video live in another android device.what should i do for recording video and playing at same time in another device.

Comment: Camera interfaces, video protocols, network topology, buffering etc.  This is a bit broad, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a thread for recording a video and in the same time stream it to the next device using a TCP socket connection. you can have the full code for this in the spy-droid application ,go here https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/ in this spydroid application that have created this live video streaming server that can be accessed from any device or any computer by simply typing the ip and port number in the browser itself. after downloading the spydroid source code you can import the packages to your project and can use them in your project

Comment: in spy-droid i could not be able to figure out communication bw one android device to another device for video streaming.make me clear about this doubt

Comment: What is that you don't understand

Comment: ya i could not be able to understand

Comment: i mean which part that u find not understandable

Comment: my problem is i should implement live video from one device to another device.i saved video file in sd card and i transfered to another device through socket connection and i received that file in another device.saved in sd card and played successfully but i should implement live video.so what i should do? plz help me